# Reports hosted in same on-premise Power Bi Report Server pointing to different cubes

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I need to have many equal reports, but the SSAS cube data source of these reports will be different instances. Any of the similar reports need to point to one of my cube instances.

Example:

```
Report A -> LiveConnection to Cube in Server1
Report B -> LiveConnection to Cube in Server2
Report C -> LiveConnection to Cube in Server3
```

I Want host these similar Reports in the same on-premise PowerBIReportServer. Is possible to have reports that point to different instances hosted in the same Report Server?

Obs: 'Report A' only will connect to 'Server 1', the same to the other reports.

I want one report server for many SSAS cubes

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Report Server can host reports that point to a number of data sources, it is not limited to just one instance of SSAS or other source

[Power BI Report Server Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/data-sources)

Comment: Jonee, thank you for answer my question, but the link above was not clear about Live Connection to multiple instances.

In a course that I saw was said that the entire Report Server only can do live connection to one data source. I know that a single report only can do Live Connection to a unique data source, but the entire Report Server limited to a single live connection, like the teacher said, is my doubt. 

I know that a Report alone is limited to a single Live Connection to SSAS, but I don't believe that the entire Report Server is limited to a single SSAS.

Thank You!!

Comment: One report is limited to one live connection, the report server is not limited to the number of reports, that have different live connections. I have a report server with reports, some point at a UAT cube the other a PROD cube

Comment: Thank you again, Jonee. Your answer helped me a lot!